# Can't fetch data from Api using Axios (with no server)

Tags: reactjs, axios

So, I'm working on a task, which says to fetch data using Axios, but without mentioning using a server, And when I tried to fetch data using Axios I got an error. The error is:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.first.org/data/v1/teams' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

And here is my code in ASP React:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://api.first.org/data/v1/teams',
      headers: { 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
      },
    };
    
    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })

    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  },[])
```

So my real question is, Can I get it to work without using a server, and I want to learn if this does and can work without a server. Because it's an Open API, and using Postman it's working, but when I do request Isn't.

Comment: Can't believe, I got unvoted, someone here around is just unvoting for fun.

Answer (score 0):

There are two suggestion way from me, if you want to try axios but no deployed server.

1. Using axios-mock-adapter, so you can perform api call without using deployed server, but you have to mock to request by yourself. https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter
2. Self-serving server in localhost, maybe you can use json-server and access it via localhost https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server

Comment: Let me add one, Proxy Cors.

Comment: But the question was, can I do without a server? @ReiiYuki

Comment: The first suggestion, no real server needed :)